# CSS - text wrapping in div

Tags: css

I'm trying to get some text in a div to display its entire contents.  It seems to me like a no-brainer but for some reason, I can't seem to get it working. everything that I've tried still crops the text at the edge of the container.

I thought that `word-wrap: break-word;` would do the trick but I had no luck with it. I've spent more than sometimes looking and trying different options all lead me to this post.

I'm not sure if the problems are caused by additional attributes set by the parent objects, or default attributes set by the Squarespace template…

The container div has a `.margin-wrapper` class and the text div has a `.image-slide-title` class.

This is what I'm working with at the moment https://cesare-asaro.squarespace.com/work .

CSS:

```
#portfolio  {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: rgba(239,93,85,1); 
      .margin-wrapper:hover { //for portfolio hovers
    position: relative;
      }  
      .margin-wrapper:after{ //for portfolio hovers
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .7s;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s;
    transform: scale(0.935);
      }  
      img { //for portfolio hovers
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
      }
      .margin-wrapper:hover:after { //for portfolio hovers
    opacity: 1;
      } 
      .margin-wrapper:hover .image-slide-title{
    color: green;
      }
      .margin-wrapper{
    border: 1px solid red;    
      }
      .image-slide-title{  
    font-size: 76px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 10px;
        color:yellow;
        position: absolute;
        margin: -97%  3.25%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    height:93.5%;
    width: 93.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `whitespace:no-wrap` from `.sqs-gallery-block-grid.sqs-gallery-block-meta-only-title .margin-wrapper .image-slide-title` and set a `line-height` for `.image-slide-title`

Comment: The whitespace:no-wrap was the problem thanks for the help!